# How to check if a date is an element of a two- date pair python

Tags: python, datetime

I have two csv files, file 1 and file 2, which contain different information. The second column of both csv files contains a date. I want to determine if any date in file 2 is contained between a date-time pair from file 1. By this, I mean contained between two consecutive dates from file 1. I also have an additional constraint that I require  the field in column four of file 1  to be non zero.

**File 1**

```
42  08/06/2017 00:00    1   15  0
42  08/06/2017 00:15    5   11  75
42  08/06/2017 00:30    0   15  0
42  08/06/2017 00:45    85  475 0
42  08/06/2017 01:00    125 75  0
42  08/06/2017 01:15    0   0   0
42  08/06/2017 01:30    95  475 0
42  08/06/2017 01:45    0   75  2.625
42  08/06/2017 02:00    0   15  0
42  08/06/2017 02:15    0   13.5    1.5
42  08/06/2017 02:30    0   1.29623 3.15814
42  08/06/2017 02:45    0   7.5 15
42  08/06/2017 03:00    0   0   15
```

**File 2**

```
42  2017-06-07-232240
42  2017-06-08-012636
42  2017-06-08-013811
42  2017-06-08-014553
42  2017-06-08-014751
42  2017-06-08-101332
42  2017-06-08-101558
42  2017-06-08-102707
42  2017-06-08-104039
42  2017-06-08-105516
42  2017-06-08-110620
```

**Latest Attempt**

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from datetime import datetime,date,timedelta


def try_parsing_date(text):

    for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%s', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M','%d/%m/%Y','%H:%M:%S','%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.%f'):
        try:
            date_strip = datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
            return date_strip 
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found')

def append_dates(a,b):
    date_1_vec = []
    date_2_vec = []
    with open(a) as file1:
        reader1 = csv.reader(file1,delimiter = ',')
        for row in reader:
            date_1_vec.append(datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"))
        with open(b) as file2:
        feed_bin = []
        upd_vec = []
        nothing = [0]
        reader2 = csv.reader(file2,delimiter = ',')              

        for row in reader2:
            temp_date = datetime.strptime(row[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            temp_date2 = temp_date + timedelta(minutes=15)
            test_val = float(row[4])
            if any(   (temp_date < dat for dat in date_1_vec) and (temp_date2 > dat for dat in date_1_vec) and (test_val >nothing for nothing in nothing)  ):
                feed_bin.append(1)
                val = 1
                #print("yes")
            else:
                feed_bin.append(0)
                val = 0
                #print("No")
            upd = [row[0],row[1],row[2],val]
            upd_vec.append(upd)
    np.savetxt("outfile.csv",upd_vec, delimiter=",", fmt='%s') 

def main():
    append_dates("file1.csv","file2.csv")
main()
```

I have tried a few different ideas but have so far been unsuccessful. The problem with my current approach is that (I think) the condition is always being met as it is searching through all dates in file 1 as opposed to consecutive dates as I require.

Any suggestions on how to modify my code, or a completely new approach would be greatly appreciated!

**Update after Jurgy's suggestions - current output:**

```
2017-06-14 13:51:57 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:57:34 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:51:57 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:57:34 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:51:57 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:57:34 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:51:57 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 13:57:34 is between 2017-06-14 13:45:00 and 2017-06-14 14:00:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
2017-06-14 16:42:03 is between 2017-06-14 16:30:00 and 2017-06-14 16:45:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about iterating through the rows of file 1 and for each row, iterate trough the rows of file 2 to see if one of these dates is inbetween the last two rows of file 1. This might be optimized by first extracting all the dates of file 2 so you don't have to open te file each time. If the dates from file 1 are not always in consectutive order, you can also first check if prev_day < cur_day without opening file 2.

```
def append_dates(a,b):
    cur_day, prev_day = None, None
    with open(a) as file1:
        for f1row in csv.reader(file1,delimiter = ','):
            cur_day = datetime.strptime(f1row[1], "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"))
            if prev_day == None:
                prev_day = cur_day
                continue
            with open(b) as file2:
                for f2row in csv.reader(file2,delimiter = ','):
                    f2day = datetime.strptime(f2row[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    if prev_day <= f2day <= cur_day:
                        print("{} is between {} and {}".format(f2day, prev_day, cur_day))
            prev_day = cur_day
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful solution! It is nearly doing what I want, but is currently printing to screen multiple time per correct condition. I am trying to figure out why this is

Comment: I also added $with open(b) as file2:$ after your continue statement

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot the open(b). This solution will print multiple times per f1row if multiple rows of f2 are inbetween two dates in f1. If you want to pick the first one, you can add a break after the print.

Comment: I don't think that is quite what it is doing, for example, see the output from my latest edit

Comment: Hmm, strange. It appears that it doesn't iterate through the rows of either file correctly. Do you correctly update prev_day after each f1row?

Comment: Yes. I am updating correctly. I will try and figure it out!

Comment: As far as I know it should work on the example you provided, so please check your other code. [Link](https://repl.it/MI78/0)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I made an error by not deleting temp files I was using to merge into file!